# How do i convert JSON VGG file annotations into YOLOv3 annotation format?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, data-annotations, yolo

I am working on a deep learning model for plate detection using YOLOv3 object detector, i used VGG Image Annotator on 1470 images and exported them on both JSON and CSV format :
[VGG annotation in JSON format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAHEO.png)

[VGG annotation in CSV format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbUP5.png)

As you can see i used polygons and rectangles because some of the plates had awkward shapes, i tried converting them into YOLOv3 format annotations but i am having trouble doing so.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but for the TensorFlow Object Detection API. First, YOLO does not take polygons as input, only rectangles, so you'd have to convert those first. Second, YOLO takes object positions relative to the image size, i.e. the objects `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax` and `ymax` go from 0 to 1. Since the VGG Image Annotator does not provide the image dimensions in the annotations, it's impossible to perform the conversion you're asking only by using the information in the JSON. You can try opening the images in a Python script and fetching their width and height using PIL.

Comment: [This issue](https://gitlab.com/vgg/via/issues/179) explains one of the problems I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The Yolo v3 I knew of has annotations in the format of 
`[classID, x_center, y_center, w, h]`, except classID is an integer, all the rest four numbers are real between 0 and 1 normalized by `image_height (H)` and `image_width (W)`, respectively. So to get a `[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max]`, one need to

1. Correct the offset

```
[x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1] = [x_center - w/2, y_center - h/2, x_center + w/2, y_center + h/2]
```

2. Apply the size

```
[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max] = [x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1] \dot_product [W H W H]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is not very clear. Please edit it.

Comment: Thank you Jasmonate! Everything will be clear when you came across the convert() and deconvert() functions in main.py found on https://github.com/ManivannanMurugavel/Yolo-Annotation-Tool-New-

Answer (score 0):

The following Python script allows you to convert JSON VGG file annotations into YOLOv3 annotation format.

```
from PIL import Image
from os import path, makedirs
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import sys
import argparse


def get_parent_dir(n=1):
    """returns the n-th parent dicrectory of the current
    working directory"""
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    for k in range(n):
        current_path = os.path.dirname(current_path)
    return current_path


sys.path.append(os.path.join(get_parent_dir(1), "Utils"))
from Convert_Format import convert_vott_csv_to_yolo

Data_Folder = os.path.join(get_parent_dir(1), "Data")
VoTT_Folder = os.path.join(
    Data_Folder, "Source_Images", "Training_Images", "vott-csv-export"
)
VoTT_csv = os.path.join(VoTT_Folder, "Annotations-export.csv")
YOLO_filename = os.path.join(VoTT_Folder, "data_train.txt")

model_folder = os.path.join(Data_Folder, "Model_Weights")
classes_filename = os.path.join(model_folder, "data_classes.txt")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # surpress any inhereted default values
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    """
    Command line options
    """
    parser.add_argument(
        "--VoTT_Folder",
        type=str,
        default=VoTT_Folder,
        help="Absolute path to the exported files from the image tagging step with VoTT. Default is "
        + VoTT_Folder,
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "--VoTT_csv",
        type=str,
        default=VoTT_csv,
        help="Absolute path to the *.csv file exported from VoTT. Default is "
        + VoTT_csv,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--YOLO_filename",
        type=str,
        default=YOLO_filename,
        help="Absolute path to the file where the annotations in YOLO format should be saved. Default is "
        + YOLO_filename,
    )

    FLAGS = parser.parse_args()

    # Prepare the dataset for YOLO
    multi_df = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.VoTT_csv)
    labels = multi_df["label"].unique()
    labeldict = dict(zip(labels, range(len(labels))))
    multi_df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=True)
    train_path = FLAGS.VoTT_Folder
    convert_vott_csv_to_yolo(
        multi_df, labeldict, path=train_path, target_name=FLAGS.YOLO_filename
    )

    # Make classes file
    file = open(classes_filename, "w")

    # Sort Dict by Values
    SortedLabelDict = sorted(labeldict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    for elem in SortedLabelDict:
        file.write(elem[0] + "\n")
    file.close()
```